# Linking js file to hbs file

Tags: javascript

I'm having great difficulty trying to link my js file to one of my hbs files. For some context, within my hbs file I have:

`<script src="../homepage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Now, the homepage.js file is found one folder above where the hbs file is located, so thats why I'm using ../ in th src. When I try to run my app, however, I am met with "homepage.js 404 error" in the browser console.

If anyone knows what could be going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`homepage.js` may not be in your webroot. If this code is in a page in your root directory, then your are asking the browser to retrieve something that you have not made publicly available.